# AWS RDS PostgreSQL: How to adjust wal_level from 'replica' to 'minimal'?

Tags: postgresql, logging, amazon-rds, wal

Our AWS RDS PostgreSQL v.16 db uses `wal_level=replica`. This causes more data to be written to the transaction logs (for PITR recovery ++). We'd like to reduce logging in order to increase performance, and have no need of PITR here. But can't figure out how to set `wal_level=minimal`.

We know that the RDS-parameter `logical_replication` determines if `wal_level` is set to "logical" or not. And the value "minimal" is supposedly the default setting. But what might cause our `wal_level` to be set to "replica"?

Tried searching, but all hits are in regard to changing it from/to "logical". Not between "minimal" and "replica".